# Do pre-processor macros for debug log statements have a place in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, macros, c-preprocessor

Recently I have been reading Effective C++ Second Edition by Scott Meyers to improve on C++ best practices. One of his listed items encourages C++ programmers to avoid pre-processor macros and 'prefer the compiler'. He went as far as saying there are almost no reasons for macro in C++ aside from #include and #ifdef/#ifndef.

I agree with his reasoning, as you can accomplish the following macro

```
#define min(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

with the following C++ language features

```
template<class T>
inline const T & min(const T & a, const T & b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

where inline gives the compiler the option to remove the function call and insert inline code and template which can handle multiple data types who have an overloaded or built in > operator.

**EDIT--** This template declaration will not completely match the stated macro if the data type of a and b differ. See Pete's comment for an example.

However, I am curious to know if using macros for debug logging is a valid use in C++. If the method I present below is not good practice, would someone be kind to suggest an alternative way?

I have been coding in Objective-C for the last year and one of my favorite 2D engines (cocos2d) utilized a macro to create logging statements. The macro is as follows:

```
/*


* if COCOS2D_DEBUG is not defined, or if it is 0 then
 *  all CCLOGXXX macros will be disabled
 *
 * if COCOS2D_DEBUG==1 then:
 *      CCLOG() will be enabled
 *      CCLOGERROR() will be enabled
 *      CCLOGINFO() will be disabled
 *
 * if COCOS2D_DEBUG==2 or higher then:
 *      CCLOG() will be enabled
 *      CCLOGERROR() will be enabled
 *      CCLOGINFO() will be enabled
 */


#define __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%s : %@",__FUNCTION__,[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])

#define __CCLOG(s, ...) \
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])


#if !defined(COCOS2D_DEBUG) || COCOS2D_DEBUG == 0
#define CCLOG(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG == 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG > 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif // COCOS2D_DEBUG
```

This macro provides for incredible utility which I will want to incorporate in my C++ programs. Writing a useful log statement is as simple as

```
CCLOG(@"Error in x due to y");
```

What is even better, is that if the COCOS2D_DEBUG is set to 0, then these statements never see the light of day. There is no overhead for checking a conditional statement to see if logging statements should be used. This is convenient when making the transition from development to production. How could one recreate this same effect in C++?

So does this type of macro belong in a C++ program? Is there a better, more C++ way of doing this?

Comment: I believe your "CCLOG()" is an excellent example of where macros are useful and appropriate.  IMHO...

Comment: Um, that `min` template function does **not** do the same thing as the macro. Try it with `min(1, 2L)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not a guru with templates but could this be the case due to 1 being an int and 2L being a long? The template declaration I provided will only generate functions for two objects of the same type.

Comment: @PaulRenton - yes, indeed. That doesn't make the template bad; it's the way that `min` is defined in the standard library.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good catch. I will make a note that they are not completely similar.

Comment: Using Objective C in C++ code is not normally considered good practice.  You should at least identify what you're up to there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Scott's statement was made at a time when macros were
considerably overused, for historical reasons.  While it is 
generally true, there are a few cases where macros make sense.
Of of these *is* logging, because only a macro can automatically
insert `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.  Also, only a macro can
resolve to absolutely nothing (although based on my experience,
this isn't a big deal).

Macros such as you show aren't very frequent in C++.  There are
two usual variants for logging:

```
#define LOG( message ) ... << message ...
```

which allows messages in the form `" x = " << x`, and can be
completely suppressed by redefining the macro, and

```
#define LOG() logFile( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

where `logFile` returns a wrapper for an `std::ostream`, which
defines `operator<<`, and permits such things as:

```
LOG() << "x = " << x;
```

Done this way, all of the expressions to the right of `LOG()`
will always be evaluated, but done correctly, no formatting will
be done unless the log is active.

Answer (score 2):

There are "right" things to use macros for and there are bad uses of macros. Using macros where functions work is a bad idea. Using macros where functions DON'T do the same thing is perfectly good in my book.

I quite often use constructs like this:

```
#defien my_assert(x) do { if (!x) assert_failed(x, #x, __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)

template<typename T> 
void assert_failed(T x, const char *x_str, const char *file, int line)
{
   std::cerr << "Assertion failed: " << x_str << "(" << x << ") at " << file << ":" << line << std::endl;
   std::terminate();
}
```

Another trick using the stringizing "operator" is something like this:

```
enum E
{
   a, 
   b, 
   c,
   d
 };

 struct enum_string
 {
    E v;
    const char *str;
 };

 #define TO_STR(x) { x, #x }

 enum_string enum_to_str[] = 
 {
    TO_STR(a),
    TO_STR(b),
    TO_STR(c),
    TO_STR(d),
  };
```

Saves quite a bit of repeating stuff...

So, yes, it's useful in some cases.